# Why am I returning an Async<unit> instead of an Async<Result>?

Tags: f#

**Problem:**

I am struggling to figure out how to model a function that returns an Async Result type.

Example:

```
type Get<'requestor,'item,'error> = 'requestor -> Async<Result<'item list,'error>>
```

NOTE:

I didn't run into this issue until I had to write C# code that relies on an F# function type. Hence, my C# code is performing IO and as a result wants to use a Task type.

**Failed Attempt:**

I want to write idiomatic F# code and do not want to sprinkle C# Task types all over my F# signatures.

For example, I don't want to do this:

```
type Get<'requestor,'item,'error> = 'requestor -> Task<Result<'item list,'error>>
```

My challenge is that I haven't figured out a way to return:

```
Async<Result<'item list,'error>>
```

Here's an example of my failure:

```
let someLongRunningOperation = async { Ok [1] } // Returns Async<unit> instead of AsyncResult
```

**Conclusion:**

In conclusion, how can I return an Async Result type referencing the following failed example:

```
let someLongRunningOperation = async { Ok [1] }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside a computation expression, you need to use the `return` keyword to wrap values in that CE's types. So this:

```
let someLongRunningOperation = async { Ok [1] }
```

should be corrected to this:

```
let someLongRunningOperation = async { return Ok [1] }
```

And then you'll be returning an `Async<Result>`.